# pip3 upgrade doesn't work

Tags: python, package, upgrade

I am programming a python package. Sometimes I want to change something about one file, and then reinstall the package using pip3. To install the package, I used:

```
make package
sudo -H pip3 install path_to_.whl_file --upgrade
```

This works for example to install the library for the first time. But if I change something about my files and then run these commands again, code that includes my package will still use the old version. I tried deleting the package from my local directory, in which case it is created again, but even then still with the old version.

I think it has to do with the make command. If I run make, it does not copy certain files, it says "not copying X (output up-to-date)". But it is not up to date, so I'm not sure why this happens.

EDIT:
In case anyone ever happens to google because he's running into the same problem: for me it worked to delete the build/lib directory, then make the package and then pip3 install the upgrade.